# Restrict concurrent session and give proper message to the user using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to restrict my second session, while same user try to log in from different machine.
Following is my Spring Security code:

```xml
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthSuccessHandler"
        login-page='/login' username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>

<logout logout-success-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,the_cookie"/>

<session-management>
    <concurrency-control session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" max-sessions="1"/>
</session-management>
```

Now using this I can restrict concurrent session but I am not able to give proper message to user like: "USER ALREADY LOGGED IN FROM DIFFERENT MACHINE".

Answer (score 0):

Implement or extend an authentication failure handler for e.g. SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler

```
public class CustomFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    setDefaultFailureUrl("/loginfailed.jsp?status=" + "YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE");
    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
}
}
```

Comment: this solved my problem. But now I am facing one problem like, if the user close the browser or shutdown the computer without logout, then same user can't do login from any other machine. User needs to do login from same machine. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Catch the window's unload event on the client side and hit the logout URL from there. So everytime the user closes the browser, he will be logged out first.